# Preventing users from resizing columns widths in ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView In My Winform that has 4columns, Name, Money, ID and Level.

The problem is when I run my app, I still have the ability to mess with the columns widths
and change them.

I searched And found that I should do something like this:

```
private void listView1_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e)
{
  e.Cancel = true;
  e.NewWidth = listView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;
}
```

But the problem is that when I debugged and Ccanged the columns widths, this event didn't even fire!

Why didn't it fire?

And how can I make the column widths fixed?

I made a new winform app just in case if there was something wrong in my old one, 
it fired, but only for the first time running the app .. here's the code:

```
namespace CsharpWinformTestingStuff
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      listView1.ColumnWidthChanging += new ColumnWidthChangingEventHandler(listView1_ColumnWidthChanging);
    }

    void listView1_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e)
    {

      e.Cancel = true;
      e.NewWidth = listView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;
    }
  }
}
```

here is the initialize component just in case you might wanna know:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
  this.listView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
  this.columnHeader1 = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
  this.columnHeader2 = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
  this.columnHeader3 = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
  this.SuspendLayout();
  // 
  // listView1
  // 
  this.listView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
        this.columnHeader1,
        this.columnHeader2,
        this.columnHeader3});
  this.listView1.GridLines = true;
  this.listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
  this.listView1.Name = "listView1";
  this.listView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 275);
  this.listView1.TabIndex = 0;
  this.listView1.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
  this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
  // 
  // columnHeader1
  // 
  this.columnHeader1.Text = "Name";
  this.columnHeader1.Width = 97;
  // 
  // columnHeader2
  // 
  this.columnHeader2.Text = "Age";
  this.columnHeader2.Width = 52;
  // 
  // columnHeader3
  // 
  this.columnHeader3.Text = "Email";
  this.columnHeader3.Width = 157;
  // 
  // Form1
  // 
  this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
  this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
  this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(308, 299);
  this.Controls.Add(this.listView1);
  this.Name = "Form1";
  this.Text = "Form1";
  this.ResumeLayout(false);

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to fix the column width of a listview in c# windows form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460308/how-to-fix-the-column-width-of-a-listview-in-c-sharp-windows-form)

Comment: it fires. Try ensuring the event is being registered properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express). We have implemented **AllowResize** property on the columns, which does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 15):

You need to register the ColumnWidthChanging event with your form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // This line registers the event, soc that the form can "hear" it and call the indicated handling code:
        this.listView1.ColumnWidthChanging += new ColumnWidthChangingEventHandler(listView1_ColumnWidthChanging);
    }

    void listView1_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Column Resizing");
        e.NewWidth = this.listView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean, the rest of your Form code. Obviously, there is something going on which is preventing the event from occurring normally.

Comment: Very sorry about the delayed answers ..
You were right, there was some problem in my code, 
I made a new winform project, just with a listview inside, 
just to check if the event was firing, at first, it fired, but then it didn't .. (only the first time I ran the program it fired)

Comment: Try setting e.Cancel = true AFTER you set the e.NewWidth Value

Comment: @XIVSolutions this works perfectly and that's what I'am looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Just click on the **Properties**>>**Events**>>**ColumnWidthChanging**.

[image]

Then add this code:

```
private void lstItems_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        e.NewWidth = lstItems.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;
    }
```

Happy coding! ^_^

Comment: I'm surprised cancelling doesn't just prevent the change anyway - do you need the second line?

Comment: yes sir, by getting the **current** Width of the listView column and passing it as **NewWidth**, we are ALWAYS setting the width to the current width.

By the way, **BRIDGE**, is the Application Name of my current program... ^_^

Comment: Don't worry it hasn't grown sentient, I am a person!

Answer (score 0):

If some one here would like to restrict only some colums on the grid, use this code.

```
        {
            if (listView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Index == 3 || listView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Index == 4 || listView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Index == 5 || listView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Index == 6)

            {
                //Do nothihng
            }
       
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                e.NewWidth = lvwItems.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;
            }
        }
```