# c# how can listview columns set unsizable?

Tags: c#

I want to use listview without sizable columns.

I looked google but there is nothing about that.

It's simple I want to use fixed columns.

Thx!

Comment: [googled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44409370/2716623) without any problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to fix the column width of a listview in c# windows form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460308/how-to-fix-the-column-width-of-a-listview-in-c-sharp-windows-form)

Comment: @LouisGo yeah it solved  thx man

Answer (score 0):

listView size set constant value
listView - нхээ хэмжээг тогтмолоор өгөөд баганыхаа хэмжээг өчгих

```
listView.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 0);
listView.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 0);
```

Comment: nope its sizing listview's sizes. i just want to for columns.